# Simple Positive Phrase in Rebus

Tags: visual, rebus

See if you can solve the following rebus.

[image: rebus puzzle]

The answer is a positive, productive phrase.

Comment: If the last symbol in the first row wasn't there, I'd have one. lol

Comment: @LukasRotter Lol! You can post your solution for the rest of them if you want, and then someone could build off of it!

Comment: I have rot13(V nz tbaan or evtug ba/bire vg)

Comment: @LukasRotter I see. You've got everything correct except that one word haha.

Comment: @LukasRotter You might just be missing rot13(onpx)

Comment: Nice that's correct @Stiv! Either of you can post the answer when you're ready. @LukasRotter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Phrase:

> I am gonna be right back on it

Explanation:

> $\sqrt{-1} = i$
>  a.m. = **am**
>  'Song' in hindi = 'gaana', pronounced a bit like "**gonna**"
>  bee = **be**
>  arrow pointing to the **right**
>  (credits to @Stiv) **back**
>  **on it**